# How can I draw a image loaded from an asset on a Canvas object

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm toying with Flutter and I have implemented a custom-drawn widget using `CustomPainter` class.

Primitives are quite well documented. However, it seems that there's `Image` (the widget) and `Image` (the data structure), because if I istantiate an `Image` (the widget) I cannot pass it to the Canvas method `drawImage` because it needs another type of `Image`.

Problem is, I cannot wrap my head on how to load a resource into an `Image` data structure.

Has anyone tackled this problem?

[edit] Thanks to **rmtmckenzie** I solved it this way:

```
rootBundle.load("assets/galaxy.jpg").then( (bd) {
  Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
  UI.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then( (codec) {
    codec.getNextFrame().then(
      (frameInfo) {
        bkImage = frameInfo.image;
        print ("bkImage instantiated: $bkImage");
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784225/flutter-how-to-draw-an-image-on-canvas-using-drawimage-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this, you need to load the image directly, and then instantiate it.

I'll leave the loading part up to you - you're either going to have to do an [Http request](https://flutter.io/networking/) directly or use [`AssetBundle.load`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html); or you could possibly use a [NetworkImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html)/[AssetImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html) (which both inherit ImageProvider - see [the docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) which contain an example).

If you take the loading directly route, you can then instantiate an image (in the form of a codec -> frame -> image) using [instantiateImageCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/instantiateImageCodec.html).

If you take the other route, you have to listen to streams etc as it is done in the docs, but you should get an Image directly.

Edit:
Thanks to the OP who has included the working code in his question. Here is what worked for him:

```
rootBundle.load("assets/galaxy.jpg").then( (bd) {
  Uint8List lst = new Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
  UI.instantiateImageCodec(lst).then( (codec) {
    codec.getNextFrame().then(
      (frameInfo) {
        bkImage = frameInfo.image;
        print ("bkImage instantiated: $bkImage");
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post a example.

Comment: @SebastianRoth the question was edited to show what the OP did. I've edited my answer to include that. If that's not enough let me know what you're having trouble with, although it might warrant a new question...

Comment: only two things to clarify: 1) where does rootBundle come from 2) does this method support loading density dependent graphics?

Comment: for 1), take a look at the [flutter asset docs](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/). And the answer to 2) is also at that link - `Flutter can load resolution-appropriate images for the current device pixel ratio.`

Comment: is it under getnextframe.then ( frameInfo { } ), I can do some painting? i'm trying to dynamically draw a frame around my asset image and finally "save" it as Bitmapdescriptor type Google Map Marker.   @rmtmckenzie

Comment: @NinFudj that is a pretty advanced usecase. To be able to "save" images I'm pretty sure you're going to need to draw it onto a canvas and then export that. That'd be a good candidate for a question all of its own

Answer (score 16):

A working solution:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

/// Load [Image] from asset path.
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/61338308/1321917
Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String assetPath) async {
  final data = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
  final list = Uint8List.view(data.buffer);
  final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(list, completer.complete);
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer