# Flutter - How to draw an Image on Canvas using DrawImage method

Tags: android, canvas, dart, flutter

I'm trying to draw an image file into the canvas to compose my widget in Flutter.

I did follow [canvas documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImage.html) but a did not success. O [Image docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html), thay say that:

> To obtain an Image object, use instantiateImageCodec.

I did try use `instantiateImageCodec` method, but i just get a `Codec` instance, not a [Image](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html)

How is the right way to get an instance of ui.Image to draw on canvas using `canvas.drawImage`

Here is a snnipet of my code:

```
Future<ui.Codec> _loadImage(AssetBundleImageKey key) async {
  final ByteData data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);
   if (data == null)
  throw 'Unable to read data';
   return await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
}

final Paint paint = new Paint()
  ..color = Colors.yellow
  ..strokeWidth = 2.0
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

var sunImage = new ExactAssetImage("res/images/grid_icon.png");

sunImage.obtainKey(new ImageConfiguration()).then((AssetBundleImageKey key){
  _loadImage(key).then((ui.Codec codec){
    print("frameCount: ${codec.frameCount.toString()}");
    codec.getNextFrame().then((info){
      print("image: ${info.image.toString()}");
      print("duration: ${info.duration.toString()}");
      canvas.drawImage(info.image, size.center(Offset.zero), paint);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

This simple utility method returns a `Future<UI.Image>` given the image asset's path:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as UI;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<UI.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  final Completer<UI.Image> completer = Completer();
  UI.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), (UI.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

ui.Codec has a method `getNextFrame()` which returns a `Future<FrameInfo>` (you should probably have logic around how many frames but if you know it's always a normal picture you could skip that.) [`FrameInfo`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/FrameInfo-class.html) has an `image` property which is the Image you need.

EDIT: looking at the code you have in the post, it's not clear where you're doing what. Is that all defined within the `CustomPainter.paint` method? If so, you'd definitely have issues because you can only use the `canvas` for the duration of the `paint` call; you should not retain any references to it outside of the function (which would include any asynchronous call).

I'd recommend using a FutureBuilder so that you only draw on the canvas once you've added the image.

That would look something like this:

```
Future<Image> _loadImage(AssetBundleImageKey key) async {
  final ByteData data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);
  if (data == null)
    throw 'Unable to read data';
  var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  // add additional checking for number of frames etc here
  var frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return frame.image;
}

new FutureBuilder<Image>(
  future: loadImage(....), // a Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Image loading...');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        else
          // ImageCanvasDrawer would be a (most likely) statless widget
          // that actually makes the CustomPaint etc
          return new ImageCanvasDrawer(image: snapshot.data)
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks to answer my question! I did updated my code with your suggestion and i can now access the Image object. But when I try draw with canvas method, flutter throw an exception with `Object has been disposed.`

Comment: Here is my exception:

Comment: See my edit for an example using FutureBuilder. Note that instead of using futurebuilder, you could use a StatefulWidget and simply pass in a null for the image until it is loaded (and handle null gracefully in the canvas), and setState the image into the StatefulWidget.

Comment: And I've been in trouble asking stuff like this before, but are you sure you actually want to manually draw the image using a canvas? There are much easier ways to get a border around an image (or many of the other assorted things you might want to do i.e. rotate, stretch, position, etc) if that's all you're trying to do.

Comment: This answer helped me in a game that uses a single image file to store all the various sprites in the game (using a single file is a requirement to make the game easily skinnable by users). I plan to use canvas.drawAtlas(). But maybe there is a better way to do that?

Comment: I get this error: The return type 'Image' isn't a 'Future<Image>', as defined by the method '_loadImage'

Comment: @KTWorks is that with a direct copy of the code above? It sounds like something strange is going on with your async calls.

Comment: Problem was the ui.image import.  You should mention to import from ui.image

Answer (score 3):

Simple example, based on idea from [Simon](https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/CgVEA_Zzcz4/m/PFAyV02hAgAJ)

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<ui.Image> loadImage(String imageName) async {
  final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/image/$imageName');
  return decodeImageFromList(data.buffer.asUint8List());
}

late ui.Image image;

void main() async {
  image = await loadImage('image.jpg');
  runApp(App());
}

// canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<ui.Image> images = new List<ui.Image>();
  ImagePainter(
      {Key key,
      @required this.noOfSlice,
      @required this.images,
      @required this.rotation,
      this.boxfit = BoxFit.contain})
      :
        // : path = new Path()
        //     ..addOval(new Rect.fromCircle(
        //       center: new Offset(75.0, 75.0),
        //       radius: 40.0,
        //     )),
        tickPaint = new Paint() {
    tickPaint.strokeWidth = 2.5;
  }
  final int noOfSlice;
  final tickPaint;
  final BoxFit boxfit;
  ui.ImageByteFormat img;
  ui.Rect rect, inputSubrect, outputSubrect;
  Size imageSize;
  FittedSizes sizes;
  double radius,
      rotation = 0.0,
      _x,
      _y,
      _angle,
      _radiun,
      _baseLength,
      _imageCircleradius,
      _incircleRadius,
      _imageOffset = 0.0,
      _imageSizeConst = 0.0;

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    print("image data:: $images");
    radius = size.width / 2;
    _angle = 360 / (noOfSlice * 2.0);
    _radiun = (_angle * pi) / 180;
    _baseLength = 2 * radius * sin(_radiun);
    _incircleRadius = (_baseLength / 2) * tan(_radiun);
    if (noOfSlice == 4) {
      _imageOffset = 30.0;
      _imageSizeConst = 30.0;
      _x = 8.60;
      _y = 4.10;
    } else if (noOfSlice == 6) {
      _imageOffset = 20.0;
      _x = 10.60;
      _y = 5.60;
    } else if (noOfSlice == 8) {
      _imageOffset = 40.0;
      _imageSizeConst = 30.0;
      _x = 12.90;
      _y = 6.60;
    }

    //print("circle radisu:: $_incircleRadius");

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    canvas.rotate(-rotation);
    int incr = 0;
    rect = ui.Offset((size.width / _x), size.width / _y) & new Size(0.0, 0.0);

    imageSize = new Size(size.width * 1.5, size.width * 1.5);
    sizes = applyBoxFit(
        boxfit,
        imageSize,
        new Size(size.width / 2 * .50 + _incircleRadius * .8,
            size.width / 2 * .50 + _incircleRadius * .8));
    inputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
    outputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, rect);
    if (images.length == noOfSlice && images.isNotEmpty)
      for (var i = 1; i <= noOfSlice * 2; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
          canvas.drawLine(
            new Offset(0.0, 0.0),
            new Offset(0.0, size.width / 2 - 4.2),
            tickPaint,
          );
        } else {
          canvas.save();
          canvas.translate(-0.0, -((size.width) / 2.2));
          ui.Image image = images[incr];
          if (image != null) {
            canvas.drawImageRect(
                image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, new Paint());
          }

          canvas.restore();
          incr++;
        }
        canvas.rotate(2 * pi / (noOfSlice * 2.0));
      }
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```